# Java Synchronization and Re-Entrant locking

Tags: java, multithreading

when we Synchronize on an object, is this a Re-Entrant lock? Is there a real difference between between a Synchronization lock and a Re-Entrant lock ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Why not try it out?  If it's reentrant, then a synchronized instance method should be able to call itself without blocking.

Comment: Yes, the built-in locks in Java are re-entrant. This fact is easily googlable, though---and testable, as Mark notes above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, lock by `synchronized` keyword is re-entrant. The implementation can be different between them though. For example, in earlier versions of JVM, the `ReentrantLock`'s implementation had much better through-put than `synchronized` keyword had. If or how the implementation differs is dependent on the JVM implementation/version.

In general, I tend to recommend to use the `synchronized` keyword if you don't require additional features the class `ReentrantLock` provides. But this is ultimately a preference.

Comment: unfair ReentrantLock can be faster than `synchronized`. fair `ReentrantLock` is much slower. `synchronized` is somewhat fair.